# BarcodeScanner no Phonegap/Cordova?

Tags: apache-cordova, plugin, código-de-barras

Não consigo encontrar nenhum plugin para leitor de código de barras, através da câmera do telemóvel, que funcione. Acho que já tentei todas as opções possíveis. O último que testei é o https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeDemo

Segui estes passos:

```
cordova platform add android
cordova platform build
plugman install --platform android --project --
```

https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner

O plugin é instalado com sucesso, mas depois de gerar o `apk`, passar para o telemóvel, o projeto não faz nada, a câmera não abre.

Alguém conseguiu por este plugin a funcionar? Ou outro plugin semelhante, que faça leitura de códigos de barra / Qr Codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estava a trabalhar com o André na procura por este plugin, por isso (e para futuras procuras) partilho aqui o único plugin que encontrei e que funcionou em Android: [PhoneGap Barcode Scanner Plugin com recurso ao Eclipse e ao Applaud](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt3).

Comment: Tânia, por motivos de organização do site, vou remover a segunda parte, que não responde à pergunta ali em cima. Mas fique à vontade para postá-la como uma pergunta separada.